# Read json file and download files based on file data

Tags: c#, json, hash, json.net, minecraft

This is going to a be lot of things to explain so I apologize in advance if I don't explain what I am looking for thoroughly enough, if you need me to clarify anything just ask and I will do my best.

So I am making a minecraft launcher in C# and I have gotten to the part where I need to download the assets, in the assets folder there are two folders indexes and objects, for now I am going to be focusing on the indexes folder. I already have the the launcher downloading the 1.7.10.json from http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/indexes/1.7.10.json (I would recommend downloading the file so you can look at the whole thing, no account is required to download it.) The problem comes when I am trying to read the 1.7.10.json I have tried every way I could think of and I have also tried looking for methods of reading the file online but none of them seem to work. This being said I was able to get the file read with this code and a little bit of editing to the .json file.

```
        public void SevenTenAssets()
    {
        string root = @"C:\SamplePack1";
        string Index = (root + "\\.minecraft\\assets\\indexes\\");

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Index + "1.7.10.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);
            DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["objects"];

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row["hash"]);
            }
        }


    }
```

However I don't believe that I am able to distribute edited files, not from the server owned by mojang. So this method can really be used.

but that is not the only issue. Say for a moment that I am able to read the unedited file I still need to take every hash out and insert it into this url http://resources.download.minecraft.net/ (first 2 hex letters of hash)/(whole hash) to download the file associated with said hash. Hopefully this example will make it more clear:

In the 1.7.10.json file the code looks like this.

```
{"objects": {
"realms/lang/de_DE.lang": {
  "hash": "729b2c09d5c588787b23127eeda2730f9c039194",
  "size": 7784
},
"realms/lang/cy_GB.lang": {
  "hash": "7b52463b2df4685d2d82c5d257fd5ec79843d618",
  "size": 7688
},
```

Just imagine there being a total of 686 hashes in the file, but anyway I need to take each hash out so for example the first one 729b2c09d5c588787b23127eeda2730f9c039194

then copy the first two character of each hash and create a folder named with the first two characters so in this hash it would be a folder named 72. Once the folder is created in the objects folder mentioned before it would need to go to the link mentioned before (I can't post it again in this because I have less than 10 reputation and can't post more than 2 link, but it is the link that has resource.download.minecraft not the s3.amazonaws link)

to download the file associated with said hash to the folder named 72.
You most likely see the "(first 2 hex letters of hash)/(whole hash)" part of the url that is because to download the file associated with the hash it needs to  take the first two characters of the has, in this case it is 72 and then add a / then and the entire hash which will download the file. You might also be thinking I could just put the links in the code  without have to read the json but I actually need to have it read the .json file because it needs to work with multiple versions of the .json (IE: 1.7.10.json, 1.8.json, and so on).
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: On stackoverflow, the recommended format for "chained" questions is [one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).  Is there any way for you to break this down into more atomic questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

JSON objects that contain custom, run-time-only property names, such as the JSON shown at [your updated link](http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/indexes/1.7.10.json):

> ```
> {
>   "objects": {
>     "realms/lang/de_DE.lang": {
>       "hash": "729b2c09d5c588787b23127eeda2730f9c039194",
>       "size": 7784
>     },
>     "realms/lang/cy_GB.lang": {
>       "hash": "7b52463b2df4685d2d82c5d257fd5ec79843d618",
>       "size": 7688
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Can be deserialized as a dictionary.  See [Deserialize a Dictionary](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm).  Thus the following data model can be used:

```
public class HashAndSize
{
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public long size { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectTable
{
    public Dictionary<string, HashAndSize> objects { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialized with [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) as follows:

```
        var url = @"http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/indexes/1.7.10.json";

        ObjectTable root;

        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        using (var stream = wc.OpenRead(url))
        using (var textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
        {
            root = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<ObjectTable>(reader);
        }
```

The `"realms/lang/cy_GB.lang"` strings become the dictionary keys.

**Original Answer**

I uploaded the JSON currently shown at your link http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.10/1.7.10.json to http://json2csharp.com/, which automatically generated the following classes for me:

```
public class Natives
{
    public string linux { get; set; }
    public string windows { get; set; }
    public string osx { get; set; }
}

public class Extract
{
    public List<string> exclude { get; set; }
}

public class Os
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Rule
{
    public string action { get; set; }
    public Os os { get; set; }
}

public class Library
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Natives natives { get; set; }
    public Extract extract { get; set; }
    public List<Rule> rules { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string releaseTime { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string minecraftArguments { get; set; }
    public int minimumLauncherVersion { get; set; }
    public string assets { get; set; }
    public List<Library> libraries { get; set; }
    public string mainClass { get; set; }
}
```

Having done so, I was able to download and deserialize the JSON using the following code:

```
        var url = @"http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.10/1.7.10.json";

        RootObject root;

        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        using (var stream = wc.OpenRead(url))
        using (var textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
        {
            root = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<RootObject>(reader);
        }
```

Comment: I didn't even realize I had the wrong link, thanks for pointing that out it should be fixed now. I will also try what you have suggested and get back to you and accept the answer if it works, thanks again.

Comment: excuse my ignorance when it comes to working with Json.net because I am kind of new to it but I am having trouble trying to use the code you have provided. I can't seem to get the hash out of the file, I know I didn't mention this in the question but for example how would I print the hash to a console window with Console.WriteLine. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Jamriz21 - the hashes are deserialized into a dictionary.  Take a look at https://dotnetfiddle.net/oWKurS

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help, the code you have just supplied me with works perfectly. However there is one thing that I asked in my original answer that I can't figure out, I also need to grab the first two characters of each hash. This would be to create folders and download the files. So for example if the hash is  "729b2c09d5c588787b23127eeda2730f9c039194" I would get "72" Thanks again, and sorry for so many questions like I said before I am kind of new to using Json.net.

Comment: @Jamriz21 - That's really a second question.  But you can just use [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).